# Div with text around

Tags: css

I'd like insert a div into another div, with text that goes around.

[image: example]

Comment: Per SO guidelines, you should post the code you've tried.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer for a poorly written question: https://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/dnztxfzw/

Just float the image.

```css
.container {
  background: #bada55;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
img {
  float: left;
  margin-left: -100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit molestiae, alias et dolorum qui in. Et doloribus, earum quo, libero saepe aut non quisquam corrupti nobis fuga qui tenetur at? Dolorem quo laborum nostrum! Veritatis tempore saepe ratione sint quos laudantium cum, expedita unde illum dolor eius quibusdam ipsam cumque consequuntur porro a illo. Et cum ut, atque ex iste dolorem nulla perspiciatis mollitia corrupti ratione, fugit consequuntur quam iusto error sint, totam ipsa recusandae.
  
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt=""/>Asperiores, nisi maiores, dicta et debitis quod. Ex inventore nobis adipisci placeat sunt aperiam libero cum illum commodi mollitia fuga, laboriosam, hic laudantium nisi consectetur. Voluptas sunt nobis mollitia at natus illo ipsam eum eius totam aperiam! Quibusdam porro quaerat reiciendis eius provident repellendus enim mollitia voluptatibus repellat similique, facere doloremque quos est? Sapiente impedit nisi natus expedita voluptate distinctio, dolor esse fugiat a deserunt mollitia! Cum exercitationem reiciendis consequatur tenetur, earum nobis. Quibusdam optio ad, recusandae, eligendi sequi veniam, nostrum libero dolorem animi odio mollitia voluptatibus aliquam neque id quidem aliquid eveniet, excepturi tempora totam. Repudiandae modi libero voluptatem ullam odio, delectus vero error quam voluptas, quod. Aperiam, iusto, a. Aut cum necessitatibus, est vel accusantium iusto hic perferendis, facere deserunt excepturi quis vero a sunt doloremque maiores vitae consectetur esse possimus debitis numquam! Unde aliquam accusantium eligendi minus minima in consectetur ipsam obcaecati qui nemo tenetur accusamus ea nihil fuga quibusdam inventore magnam, provident sequi, deleniti itaque quia id sint sed. Sed quibusdam praesentium tenetur a perferendis ipsam incidunt. Similique earum nesciunt laudantium nisi deleniti quia. Facere sed iure animi perspiciatis eum fugiat tenetur, necessitatibus, nostrum. Magnam asperiores quia quidem nostrum sapiente pariatur vel soluta ipsam accusantium repellendus accusamus, aperiam magni. Debitis facilis aliquam et libero, maiores animi maxime, rerum in! Ab vitae dolore, nobis, beatae et optio cumque aliquam dolores quae! Repellendus quia eos blanditiis laborum ex magni fuga vitae magnam, alias quidem perspiciatis fugit eius voluptatem velit reiciendis quod quisquam laudantium accusamus tempora non cupiditate enim deleniti soluta voluptatibus? Natus, rerum, tempora. Cumque nesciunt libero ipsam praesentium at neque, rerum ut tempora numquam dolore sint impedit animi possimus dicta est debitis sit blanditiis id eaque eius eligendi, commodi dolores tenetur. Fugiat, atque quam ratione iusto, sed illo corporis ab, totam, libero quidem doloremque sequi recusandae placeat? Accusantium quam cupiditate ad quas aut ipsum reprehenderit nam rerum, accusamus sapiente sunt, magnam fugiat tenetur harum repellendus eaque perspiciatis nesciunt ratione ipsa aliquid laudantium?</p>
</div>
```

Edit: Stackoverflow is not for having the people do the things for you. In this case I did it because I see you're pretty new and it was a quick thing. In the future try something and then come here and ask why it's not working.